# Ошибка TomCat: SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, развертывание

Учу spring, пытаюсь сделать свой первый бин. Когда пытаюсь запустить приложение в eclipse - все ок. Когда через eclipse пытаюсь запустить на TomCat - выдает ошибку в консоли.

```
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.34
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 3 2020 12:02:52 UTC
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.34.0
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           14.0.1+7
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.34
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\apache-tomcat-9.0.34
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\Eclipse projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [817] milliseconds
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:16 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
апр. 28, 2020 9:46:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1 127] milliseconds
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [GET / HTTP/1.1] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: An IO exception occurred trying to read the shutdown command
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:667)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

апр. 28, 2020 9:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [] received
апр. 28, 2020 9:56:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: An IO exception occurred trying to read the shutdown command
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:982)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:667)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

апр. 28, 2020 9:56:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: Invalid shutdown command [] received
```

Причем если открываю тот же TomCat через eclipse или хром, то выдает 404

[image: Ошибка в TomCat]

Я с java не очень хорошо дружу, тем более с локальным сервером (TomCat к слову, только сегодня установил в первый раз в своей жизни). До этого работал с php только. Может кто подсказать, как решить проблему? Или статью подходящую скинуть. Нигде не нашел решения, которое бы мне помогло.

Comment: Пробуйте использовать Inteliji Idea. Большое количество людей пользуется этой средой разработки и людям проще подсказывать. Я к сожалению с таким не сталкивался, если бы пользоваться Inteliji Idea может быть смог бы съориентировать. Если ты хочешь начать писать на Java, то рано или поздно придёшь к этому.

Comment: Axel23, спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, Inteliji Idea не поддерживает Spring в бесплатной версии. Согласен, что эта IDE намного удобнее, но приходится работать с тем, что работает...

Comment: Если что на торрентах можно найти.

Comment: Однозначно проблема портами какая-то

Comment: То что удалось вычитать:

Порт администратора предназначен для приема команд администратора, а порт HTTP - для приема запросов HTTP. Вы должны использовать разные порты. 

Случилось это:
Сервер уже открыл этот порт. Ваш браузер / клиент / что бы ни отправил запрос на порт администратора, сервер не понимает HTTP и регистрирует эту ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо! Решил создать новый проект, там действительно надо было настроить порты другие. Все заработало.

Comment: Тогда оставлю ответ. Чтобы висел. Может кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Порт администратора предназначен для приема команд администратора, а порт `HTTP` - для приема запросов `HTTP`.

Вы должны использовать разные порты. Случилось это: Сервер уже открыл этот порт. Ваш браузер/клиент/ что бы ни отправил запрос на порт администратора, сервер не понимает `HTTP` и регистрирует эту ошибку.